# Contact form text area enters and scrolling

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Hello im building my wordpress site, and used contact form to build contact form. I have few questions.

1. Text in text area is one line, and when i click ENTER contact form try to send form. How to enable enters?
2. How to enable scrolling in text area?
3. When i typing text, only big letters appear, like when i using caps-lock, how to enable small letters also?

```css
    /*contact*/
    
.one-half,
.one-third {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 4%;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
     
.one-half { width: 48%; }
.one-third { width: 30.66%; }

.last {
  margin-right: 0 !important;
  clear: right;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .one-half, .one-third {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

#name-form { 
  background:0 0;
  border:none;
  width:100%;
  border-bottom:2px solid #FFFFFF;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-weight:900;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  font-family: Josefin Sans, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom:58px;
  font-size:14px
}

#mail-form { 
  background:0 0;
  border:none;
  width:100%;
  border-bottom:2px solid #FFFFFF;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-weight:900;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  font-family: Josefin Sans, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom:58px;
  font-size:14px
}

#phone-form {
  background:0 0;
  border:none;
  width:100%;
  border-bottom:2px solid #FFFFFF;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-weight:900;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  font-family: Josefin Sans, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom:58px;
  font-size:14px;
}

#text-form {
  background:0 0;
  border:none;
  width:100%;
  border-bottom:2px solid #FFFFFF;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-weight:900;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  font-family: Josefin Sans, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom:58px;
  font-size:14px;
  height:100px;
}


::placeholder {
  color: white;
  font-weight:900;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Josefin Sans, sans-serif;
}

.wpcf7-form > p {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
  font-weight:900;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.wpcf7-form input, .wpcf7-form textarea {
  font-weight:900;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Josefin Sans, sans-serif;
}

.wpcf7-form textarea {
  font-weight:900;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Josefin Sans, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="one-third">
    
    [text* text-757 id:name-form placeholder "IMIĘ"]
    
</div>

<div class="one-third">

    [tel tel-789 id:phone-form placeholder "TELEFON"]

</div>

<div class="one-third last">

    [email* email-910 id:mail-form placeholder "E-MAIL"]

</div>

    [text* text-757 id:text-form placeholder "WIADOMOŚĆ"]

    [submit "Wyślij"]
```

I am newbie in coding so please be forgiving :)

Comment: Are you sure it's inserting a `<textarea>` and not just an `<input type="text">`?

Comment: Yay... googling 1hour and added area to text and it works. But problem number 3 still exist. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `<textarea>` instead of `<input type="text">`.

You are also setting `text-transform:uppercase;` in the styles which will make all of the text uppercase. Remove that and it should fix your third problem.

Comment: Yay! Thanks, fixed !